# Why does passing the result of printf to another printf work?

Tags: c, printf

How does the following code work?

```
void main()
{
    printf("%d", printf("earth"));
}
```

This gives as output: `earth5`.

Comment: It works because the compiler told it to.

Comment: If you're confused about what stuff is, check out the documentation. For example, [`man 3 printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return value of `printf` is the number of characters printed.  The inner `printf` is called first.  Equivalent to:

```
int rc = printf("earth");
printf("%d", rc);
```

Comment: @KerrekSB - stands for "return code."  Standard C practice.  The terseness does not beget education but that's where the habit came from.

Comment: @djechlin The point was "...is the # of characters..." should better be "...is the number of characters...".

Comment: @DanielFischer - oh that's just this silly "First answer" culture we have around here and I didn't pick it up on an edit.

Comment: @KerrekSB "number" is hardly a good name for an `int`

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely fine :-)

The print("earth") outputs earth and return 5 (the number of characters printed).

The other printf gets the 5 as a parameter and outputs it as an integer (because of the %d)

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is expecting an integer to print it. `printf` returns the number of printed chars, and you're printing a 5 char string.

It evaluates first the inner print to find out how many character were printed and then it evaluates the outer one printing 5.