# printf without a specifier

Tags: c, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does passing the result of printf to another printf work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625920/why-does-passing-the-result-of-printf-to-another-printf-work)

I have a code snippet..

```
printf("%d", printf("tim"));
```

The function printf prints the value, tim3 .. The second printf statement does not have a specifier so why do the number of characters get printed along with the string "tim" ?

When i only run this code .. `printf("tim");` i get output as, `tim Exited: ExitFailure 3` Why does this happen?

And how does the 1st printf statement takes `printf("tim")` as an argument when it is expecting an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` prints the string as it is if no format specifier is specified. So `printf("Hello");` will print `Hello` as it is.

You can also do the same by using a format specifier like so - `printf("%s", "Hello");`

`printf` also returns the number of characters printed. So `printf("Hello");` first prints the string `Hello` and then returns `5`.

In your statement, you're printing the return statement of `printf` using `printf("%d", ...);`

In effect, the statement that you've given can be written like this -

```
int i = printf("tim");
printf("%d", i);
```

As for the failure, I'm guessing you have a `return printf("tim");` in your `main` function.

Comment: that made things better :) thanks

Comment: As for the failure, I think it's more likely that he has no return at all in `main`, and the compiler is in pre-C99 mode, so it's undefined behaviour, but the return value of `main` then is what happens to be in the return register, what would be the return value of the `printf`.

Answer (score 6):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed, so `printf("tim")` returns 3 because there are 3 characters in the string.

The second `printf` needs to be evaluated before its value can be used in the format string, hence it is printed first.

As for your output `tim Exited: ExitFailure 3`, that looks more like you have another problem which is causing a problem at the same time as it is printing. Comment out those lines and you will probably find a problem elsewhere.

Comment: so if printf prints the numbers of characters printed, why does it prints tim alongside.. 3 should be printed as the answer because of the fact that the access specifier is %d! :| ?

Comment: Printf does two things. First, it formats and prints to STDOUT. Then, it returns the number of characters.